# Adding string with left angle bracket breaks my array

Tags: php, arrays

Having a weird issue. I am trying to build an array with a string for some email recipients.

```
foreach ($to_email as $to_emails) {
    $name = $to_emails['name'];
    $username = $to_emails['username'];
    $recipient_emails_arr[] = "$name <$username>";
}
```

All the values are coming in fine in the `foreach` loop but for some reason when I use the first angle bracket `<` it seems to break the array at that point and does not include the rest of the string.

Here is what I get from the code above. As you can see the brackets and emails are not included.

`Array ( [0] => John Smith [1] => Pam Smith )`

Now let's say I remove the first angle bracket. I get this

`Array ( [0] => John Smith jsmith@example.com> [1] => Pam Smith psmith@example.com> )`

It seems to be something with that first angle bracket that breaks it. I tried using `\` to escape the brackets but that does nothing.

This is what I need to get

`Array ( [0] => John Smith <jsmith@example.com> [1] => Pam Smith <psmith@example.com> )`

What am I missing?

Comment: View source of the page in the browser.  When a browser sees a `<` it treats it as an HTML tag.

Comment: `<` is a starting symbol of any html-tag.

Comment: @AbraCadaver wow lol so simple and can make me feel so dumb

Comment: You can see with `echo htmlentities("$name <$username>");`